# W3CWebSocket or WebSocket?

Tags: сокет, websocket, socket.io

В чем разница между W3CWebSocket и обычным?
Работаю через node: [тут](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)

Comment: W3CWebSocket это просто обёртка над WebSocketClient

Comment: тогда лучше использовать простой вебсокет нежели обертку? Обертка типа для удобства?